# Custom Shape for CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-custom-view

I know I can have a `CircularProgressIndicator` to indicate some progress, but can I also give it a custom shape like this:

[image: Expected outcome]

The goal would be a semi circle with some left out elements but still would fill correctly. I think I need to write some custom view for the "100%" progress part, but how to get the custom drawable for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the answer in Compose or the regular view?

Comment: Regular. Never worked with compose actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a starting point for the custom view.
Depending on the requirement you can modify the values to get the desired UI.

```
class MyCircularProgressView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
) : View(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    private var stroke = 25F
    var size: Int = 200
        set(value) {
            field = value
            stroke = value * 0.125F
            invalidate()
        }
    var backgroundStartAngle: Float = 30F
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }
    var backgroundSweepAngle: Float = 300F
        set(value) {
            field = value    
            invalidate()
        }
    var progressStartAngle: Float = 150F
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }
    var progressSweepAngle: Float = 180F
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint()
    private val progressPaint = Paint()

    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCircularProgressView, 0, 0).apply {
            try {
              // Handle attributes passed from XMl here
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }

        backgroundPaint.apply {
            color = 0xFFE0E0E0.toInt()
            strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeWidth = stroke
        }
        progressPaint.apply {
            color = 0xFF0000EE.toInt()
            strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeWidth = stroke
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawArc(
            stroke / 2F,
            stroke / 2F,
            size.toFloat(),
            size.toFloat(),
            backgroundStartAngle % 360F,
            backgroundSweepAngle % 360F,
            false,
            backgroundPaint,
        )
        canvas.drawArc(
            stroke / 2F,
            stroke / 2F,
            size.toFloat(),
            size.toFloat(),
            progressStartAngle % 360F,
            progressSweepAngle % 360F,
            false,
            progressPaint,
        )
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        setMeasuredDimension(size + stroke.toInt(), size + stroke.toInt())
    }
}
```

**Output UI**

[image: Screenshot]